# WCF net.tcp SSL: none of the cipher suites supported by the client application are supported by the server

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, ssl, tcp

I have two PCs, let's call them PC1 and PC2.

I wrote a service-side application that opens a self-hosted WCF net.tcp endpoint, secured with an X509 certificate. The certificate I use for transport security is "Issued To" an arbitrary name, eg: MY-TEST-SERVICE.

I also wrote a client-side application to talk to the service. It knows and specifies the DnsIdentity that the service will provide (MY-TEST-SERVICE), it uses the same X509 certificate the service uses for transport security.

When I run the client on PC1, it works with the service on PC1 and PC2.

When I run the client on PC2, it works with the service on PC1 but the SSL handshake with the service on PC2 fails.

Turning on WCF client-side tracing on PC2, then connecting successfully to the secured net.tcp service on PC1 and failing to connect to the secured net.tcp service on PC2, I can see exactly which step is failing.

The trace for the successful handshake, from PC2 to PC1, reports:
- Identity was determined for an endpoint reference
- Identity verification succeeded

The trace for the failed handshake, from PC2 to PC2, reports:
- The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by...
- Throwing an exception

Why would the identity verification process fail, but only when the client and service are both executing on PC2?

Comment: is the cert in both the Local Computer > Trusted People store and the Local Computer > Personal store on PC2?

Comment: Yes. The certificate I'm using for client and server is in Local Computer Personal and its CA is in Local Computer Trusted Root, this is the case on both PC1 and PC2. The certificate has a private key and the path to the CA is verified.

Comment: Digging deeper, I see an Schannel event in the System event log:

"An TLS 1.2 connection request was received from a remote client application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client application are supported by the server. The SSL connection request has failed." 

Finally, I see the actual problem ... but how can it be that the service and client executing on the same PC disagree like this?!

Comment: @MikeZ were you able to find a solution to this problem? we are now facing the same thing.

Comment: @developer82 So sorry for the delay ... I just now saw your question ... I changed the SecurityMode from Transport to Message.

Answer (score 2):

We eventually found the problem (I don't know if it applies to your exact case) without changing anything in our code - in our case it just started one day without any code change.

We found that a Windows Update has occurred that installed `kb3102467` - which is .NET Framework 4.6.1, which we will eventually use, and probably will find itself on everyone’s machine.

It seems that the problem is that SHA512 is no longer supported in TLS 1.2 since it caused high CPU usage. We will probably need to issue new SSL certificates for both the client and the server.

As a workaround, we disabled TLS 1.2:

1. Start regedit and browse to the following location: HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SChannel\Protocols
2. Create the following Key under Protocol: TLS 1.2
3. Create the following two Keys under TLS 1.2: Client and Server
4. Create the following DWORDs under both the Client and Server Key: DisabledByDefault and Enabled
5. Under both Client and Server set the following: DisabledByDefault=1 and Enabled =0
6. Reboot the server.

This fixed our problem while still having .NET F/W 4.6.1 installed on the machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the SecurityMode on client and service from Transport to Message has resolved the original problem and all clients now work with all services.

This doesn't make sense to me, but regardless, I have a solution.